# Margins don't work with tickets

Tags: margins

I try to use the package `ticket`. However, if I set margins to 0 cm, there is still some extra space at the top. How to remove it and ensure that the distance between the top of the page and the top of the first ticket is 0 cm (or anything set at the geometry settings)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[boxed]{ticket}
\usepackage[top=0cm,left=0cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand*{\ticketdefault}{}
\newcommand*{\myticket}[1]{\ticket{\small\put(3,16){\parbox[t]{32mm}{#1}}}}

\begin{document}    
\myticket{Ticket}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that adding `\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}` to the preamble solves the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[boxed]{ticket}
\usepackage[top=0cm,left=0cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand*{\ticketdefault}{}
\newcommand*{\myticket}[1]{\ticket{\small\put(3,16){\parbox[t]{32mm}{#1}}}}


\begin{document}    
\myticket{Ticket}
\end{document}
```

[image]